# Update a nested form

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in RoR, and I'm trying to practice building a web app.
I have a classic app with User who have Post.

An other model Online is used to put the post on a common wall, and it's associated with a nested form Orders which represents pieces available.

So now, I'm trying to update Orders with the action "taked" in my post show view, but rails say that he Couldn't find Post with 'id'= with the private method set online which is working to create orders. (photo)

Error :
[image]
My code :

Onlines controller :

```html
class OnlinesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_post 
  before_action :owned_online, only: [:new, :update]
  before_action :set_online, except: [:taked]
  before_action :set_unline, only: [:taked]


  def new 
    @online = current_user.onlines.build
    @online.post_id = @post.id
    @online.user_id = current_user.id
  end 

  def edit
  end

   def taked 
  @online.orders.update(taked: false, taked_at: Time.zone.now, taked_by: current_user)
end

  def create 
      if Online.where(post_id: params[:post_id]).any?
      @online = Online.where(post_id: params[:post_id]).last.update_attributes(push: false)
      end
     @online = @post.onlines.create(online_params)
    if @online.save
      if @online.portion <= 0
          @online.update(push: false)
          flash[:success] = 'Veuillez indiquer le nombre de parts disponibles '
          redirect_to root_path 
        else
       @online.update(pushed_at: Time.zone.now)
       @online.update(push: true)

       
       flash[:success] = 'Votre post est en ligne !'
      redirect_to root_path
    
    end
    else 
      render 'new'
    end 
  end 




def update  
    if @onlines.update(online_params)
      if @online.push == false
        if @online.portion <= 0
          @online.update(push: false)
          flash[:success] = 'Veuillez indiquer le nombre de parts disponibles '
          redirect_to root_path 
        else
         @online.update(push: true)
         flash[:success] = 'Votre post a bien été pushé !'
         redirect_to root_path      
      end   
    end
    else
      @user.errors.full_messages
      flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages
      render :edit
    end
  end


private 

def online_params
  params.require(:online).permit(:user_id, :post_id, :prix, :portion, :push, :pushed_at, orders_attributes: [:id, :taked, :taked_at, :taked_by, :validated_at, :validated_by, :_destroy])
  end 

  def owned_online 
     @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  unless current_user == @post.user
    flash[:alert] = "That post doesn't belong to you!"
    redirect_to :back
  end
end  

  def set_post
  @post = Post.find_by(params[:post_id]) 
  end 


  def set_online
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @online = Online.find_by(params[:id]) 
  end 

  def set_unline
  @online = Online.find_by(params[:id]) 
end

end
```

```html
class Online < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :orders
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders, allow_destroy: true
  
  scope :push, ->{ where(push: true).order("pushed_at DESC") }
end
```

Views/posts/show :

```html
 <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <%= link_to '-  Pusher  - ', new_post_online_path(@post), data: { confirm: 'Confirmer la mise en ligne de #{@title}?' }, class: "btn btn-primary " %>


  <div class="col-md-9">
    <h3>Parts :</h3>
    <div id="Orders">
      
        <ul>
    <%- @post.onlines.each do |online| %>
      <%- online.orders.each do |order| %>
      <%- if order.taked == false %>
      <li>
  <%= link_to 'Take', taked_online_path(online), method: :update, class: "btn btn-warning"%>
      </li>
      <%end%>
      <%end%>
    <%end%>
  </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the routes :

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'profiles/show'

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }

  resources :posts do 
    resources :comments
    resources :onlines do 
      resources :orders
    end
end

  get ':pseudo', to: 'profiles#show', as: :profile
  get ':pseudo/edit', to: 'profiles#edit', as: :edit_profile
  patch ':pseudo/edit', to: 'profiles#update', as: :update_profile

 put 'online/:id/taked', to: 'onlines#taked', as: :taked_online

  
  

  root 'posts#index'
```

So if you have any advices for that, I'll take it !!
Thanks

Comment: Where exactly you get this `Couldn't find Post with 'id'=` error?

Comment: Into my online controller, in the private methods

Comment: I think the problem is coming from that line :
 <%= link_to 'Take', taked_online_path(online), method: :update, class: "btn btn-warning"%>
But I don't find how to update a attributes

Comment: Can you update your question with the full error stack and with the params that are generated in the server log?

Comment: I put you a image of the error page with all the informations, and the routes that i'v forget

Answer (score 1):

> Couldn't find Post with 'id'=

You have `before_action :set_online` which assigns `@post` with the help of `params{:post_id]` before ***any action of that cntroller got triggered***. But there is no `post_id` coming for the `taked` action, so it ***fails*** reporting that error. You can avoid this check by changing `before_action :set_online` to `before_action :set_online, except: [:taked]`, ***but this again doesn't assign*** `@online` for the `taked` action ***which is required*** for that method.

So, only option for you is to ***remove assigning*** the `@post` in the `set_online` method.

```
def set_online
  @online = Online.find_by(params[:id]) 
end
```

Further more, your code needs some changes. Firstly, the ***route*** for `taked_online` is wrong. It should be

```
put 'online/:id/taked', to: 'onlines#taked', as: :taked_online
```

as you are using it to ***update***, not for ***create***.

And finally, the `taked` method needs to be tweaked.

```
def taked 
  @online.orders.update(taked: false, taked_at: Time.zone.now, taked_by: current_user)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have applied all your advice, I think I'm very far from the goal. I duplicated the set_online method to remove @post as I put up. However, I still have an error concerant the routes after the changes, an error say "No route matches [POST] "/online/248/taked" ".
So why he thinks that I want to create a new online in my code ?

Comment: @lilipupu Did you changed the route as per my changes?

Comment: Yep, it is now in put, but the error is still in POST

Comment: @lilipupu Try restarting the server.

Comment: Well, now, I have the same error with GET. So I try with PATCH but same errors